# ActiveAdmin: Child object claims to not have method parent_object_id

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have solved this issue before but the solution currently escapes me.

I have two Models `FlsCenter` and `Airport`. FlsCenters `has_many` airports. 
In active admin I am creating a newe `Airport` object. however when I press `New Airport` in the dashboard, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `fls_center_id' for #<Airport:0x007fbf5457bf00>
```

Here are the model definitions for both models:

```
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fls_center
end



class FlsCenter < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :housing_options
  has_many :airports
  has_many :programs
end
```

Here is my Schema.rb

```
 create_table "airports", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "pick_up_cost"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

notice that there is not field `fls_center_id`. Doesn't rails take care of that via `belongs_to` `has_many`? How come my schema does not reflect my models?

I ran `rake db:migrate`. Also for reference I have included fls_center_id as a permitted param to active admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails won't create database columns for you just from setting up the model. You can add another migration to add this new field. Try:

```
rails g migration add_fls_center_to_airports fls_center:reference:index
```

And then run rake db:migrate.